# why does[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate].window.bound ≠ [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios14

When I entered an app in portrait mode and forced to switch to landscape mode, there was a problem，   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate].window ≠  [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size ：

UIWindow *keyWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate].window;

[image]

Their length and width are opposite，why？
by the way,  [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size  is  right size;

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the coordinate system that the frame and the bounds belong to:
`bounds` belongs to the coordinate system as seen from the "inside" of a view, whereas `frame` to the coordinate system of the "outside" belongs.

Think of `CGAffineTransform`: If you rotate or scale a view, it's frame changes, but the bounds stay the same.

Comment: Sorry, my description just now is wrong, now the question is updated